# WordPress admin panel global warning

Tags: wordpress

I try to find out how to register a global warning for WordPress administration panel.

I create a plugin that after activation must be enabled, in order to work.

The question not is, how can I create a warning message that will be displayed sidewide in the  WordPress admin panel ?

In example.

The plugin X is no yet enabled. Please click here to enable it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [WordPress hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) for `admin_notices`.

Put something like the following in your plugin and it will call `activation_notice()` during the output of the page.

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'activation_notice');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason ! :) Your answer was very helpfull.

Comment: If this is what you needed, mark it as answered by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Done ;) Thansk a lot again :)